# Exception on parsing test reports

Tags: java, maven, jqassistant

I added the jQA scan and analyze plugins to a maven build. Now I get the following exceptions on build:

> [INFO] Entering C:/.../target/surefire-reports [WARNING] Cannot parse
>   document '/TEST-com...Test.xml': ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
>   Message: Premature end of file. [ERROR] Cannot scan item
>   /TEST-com...Test.xml java.util.NoSuchElementException: ParseError at
>   [row,col]:[76,18] Message: The processing instruction target matching
>   "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLEventReaderImpl.next(XMLEventReaderImpl.java:252)
>     at
>   com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.junit.impl.scanner.TestReportScannerPlugin.scan(TestReportScannerPlugin.java:52)
>     at
>   com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.junit.impl.scanner.TestReportScannerPlugin.scan(TestReportScannerPlugin.java:28)
>   at 
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

I'm using jQA v 1.0.0 on a Windows 7 machine. 
If I open the test report XML files, they look quite normal. So maybe a race condition or so.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/buschmais/jqassistant/issues/210) has already been fixed for 1.1.0 - the reason was incorrect caching of streams. Despite the exception is logged the data representing the test report should be available in the database after scanning.